# Tableau Multi-database Viz - Best Practice

Tags: tableau-api

Novice Tableau author here. My project got a requirement to develop the Tableau Sales dashboard of 5 years of sales data.

The current year sale data always resides on the OLTP MSSQL database, and all prior year data got archived end of year and all resides in respective database. In summary we got 5 years of data in 5 database.

The challenges are
1) The number of years will vary from customer to customer
2) Same tableau worksheet should work for multiple customer, just pointing to the same MSSQL Instance

All database has the same schema, and what's the best way to bring this data in Tableau?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to bring all the data is to create 5 sheets with 5 different connections to 5 databases and create a dashboard with 5 sheets.

Since all databases have same schema use action filters instead of individual filters to the sheets so that performance can be improved.

Edit---------------------------------------------------------------

To my knowledge, you can't dynamically add the database connections and extract data, So for every customer report need to changed manually.

So solution still holds good because for each customer you will be adding a new connection.

Comment: Each sheet has to hold the consolidated data from all 5 database, is this approach works for this case?

Comment: I would suggest you create 5 dashboards with consolidated data imstead of combining data from 5 databases in a single sheet

Comment: I am sorry, we can't fix the number of database, I have rephrased the question for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to this as on answering this, The cross-database joins and union are still in idea face, refer this - https://community.tableau.com/ideas/7822